# Склонение мужской фамилии Бодний

Tags: склонение-фамилий

Почему склоняют мужскую фамилию **Бодний**?
[Учитель подписывает все учебники и тетради так: (кого?) Бодния.]

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, пожалуйста, отметьте его [как принятый](/help/accepted-answer) (галочка рядом с ответом) и поставьте ему значок ▲.

Answer (score 5):

> мальчик, фамилия Бодний, фамилия не склоняется...

Не склоняется эта фамилия у девочек. У мальчиков же может склоняться по образцу существительных с нулевым окончанием (типа ***кий***).

Вот что о подобных фамилиях говорится в [**ПИСЬМОВНИКЕ**](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/letters/71-rubric-482) на Грамоте.ру:

> В очень редких случаях могут быть восприняты неоднозначно фамилии,
>   исходные формы которых кончаются йотом (на письме *й*) с
>   предшествующими гласными *и* или *о.* Например, такие фамилии, как
>   *Топчий, Побожий, Бокий, Рудой* можно воспринять и как имеющие окончания *-ий, -ой* и, следовательно склоняющиеся как прилагательные
>   (*Топчего, Топчему...,* в женском роде *Топчая, Топчей*) и как имеющие
>   нулевое окончание со склонением по образцу существительных (***Топчия,
>   Топчию***..., в женском роде неизменяемая форма *Топчий*).